# Videojs rtmp can't autoplay

Tags: video.js

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Video.js RTMP Example Embed</title>
  
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video.js"></script>
  <style>
    div{
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay width="300" height="400" 
  data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="rtmp://10.0.1.49/broadcast/myapp" type='rtmp/flv'>
  </video>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the autoplay attribute. But when i load the page, the videojs big button will show a moment and disappear. After that, a little circle button will appear in the middle of the video. Just like this :

[image]

Is there anybody who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First update the videojs lib and [here](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/options.html) you can see the correct autoplay syntax. Your code should look like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>Video.js RTMP Example Embed</title>

<!-- VideoJS API -->
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11.9/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js">  </script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11.9/video.js"></script>
<style>
    div{
       float: left;
       }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload='auto' width="300" height="400" 
        <source src="rtmp://10.0.1.49:1935/broadcast/myapp" type='rtmp/flv' />
      </video>
     </div>    
 </body>
 </html>
```

In order to see the streamed video you need to make the nginx-rtmp to work. Copy this file in the root directory and restart nginx. Should work. [Here](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-started-with-nginx-rtmp) are

Comment: Thanks your advise, i have tried but the result is the same as before! When i set autoplay, the big button on the left corner will disappear, but a little button will appear on the center of the video!

Comment: The video will not play if is not streamed by a server

Comment: server is ok. i found the reason, it's flash version

Comment: I think Zhang's solution info is here: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/3748